# Django - Two objects' field can have the same value only if their foreign keys are different

Tags: python, django

Is there any built-in solution in Django for letting two objects' field having the same value only if their foreign keys are different.

E.g. two children can have the same name only if their mother is NOT the same:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    mother = models.ForeignKey(Mother, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

class Mother(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Primary keys are always different, by definition.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, I think you are looking for [unique together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Comment: thanks, it's exactly what i'd been looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make fields on a model [*unique together*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together). This means that the individual fields may be the same, so long as at least one of the fields in the *unique together* constraint are different.

```
class Mother(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    mother = models.ForeignKey(Mother, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'mother')
```

You cannot, however, enforce unique together constraints for fields on related models. For example `unique_together = ('child_field', 'mother__mother_field')` would not be allowed.